# Add arrow from two points inside the set (e.g. a circle)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows

This code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw circle (3cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I would like to add two arrows between different points of this set. For example:

[image]

Note that the starting and ending points of the arrows must be inside the circle. How could I add these arrows in my tikz code?

Comment: Maybe you want to draw the points (elements?) within your set explicitly and then use the `fit` option to construct the circle afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two ways to obtain **Bezier** curves.

1. The first one using the syntax `[out=70,in=20,looseness=2]` see the section `74 To Path Library` of the [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)
2. and the second one using the syntax `..controls (-2,-4) ..` see the section `14.3 The Curve-To Operation`

#### Update (with polar coordinate)

As Ignasi say

[image: screensot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Straight Barb[length=5mm,width=5mm]}]
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\draw[->](20:2.5)to[out=70,in=20,looseness=2](120:2.5);
\draw [->](-45:1.5) ..controls (-120:4.5) .. (190:2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### (old answer) with implicit rectangular coordinate

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Straight Barb[length=5mm,width=5mm]}]
\draw (0,0) circle (3cm);
\draw[->](2,1)to[out=70,in=20,looseness=2](-1,2);
\draw [->](1.5,-1.5) ..controls (-2,-4) .. (-2,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Being a circle at origin, I think references with polar coordinates are easier: `(30:2.1cm)` or similars

Comment: yes you are right